# Loop/Case statement is skipping over values I'm checking for?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub where I want to submit data with a command button, and before it sends the data, it has a loop that checks every control on every page of the userform. If the control is visible, and it fits within the case, then check to see if it's blank and then place that control name into an array.

the loop starts, but once I hit my first case statement loop `cmb*`, it skips over and doesn't enter the loop.

What is going on here? I have used the `Like` operator to clear fields on a sheet before, not sure why this isnt working..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim icontrol As Control
    Dim arrBlankFields As Variant
    Dim i As Long, x As Long
    For i = 0 To Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
        If Me.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Visible = True Then
            For Each icontrol In Me.Controls
                If icontrol.Visible = True Then
                    Select Case icontrol.Name
                        Case icontrol.Name Like "Multi*"
                        Case icontrol.Name Like "lbl*"
                        Case icontrol.Name Like "txt*"
                            If icontrol.Value = "" Then
                                ReDim Preserve arrBlankFields(x)
                                arrBlankFields(x) = icontrol.Name
                                x = x + 1
                            End If
                        Case icontrol.Name Like "opt*"
                            If icontrol.Value = "" Then
                                ReDim Preserve arrBlankFields(x)
                                arrBlankFields(x) = icontrol.Name
                                x = x + 1
                            End If
                        Case icontrol.Name Like "cmb*"
                            If icontrol.Value = "" Then
                                ReDim Preserve arrBlankFields(x)
                                arrBlankFields(x) = icontrol.Name
                                x = x + 1
                            End If
                    End Select
                Else
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next i
    If Len(arrBlankFields) > 0 Then
        MsgBox arrBlankFields & " fields are empty, please go back and populate before sending data"
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: try `Select Case True`

Comment: this worked, thanks Scott!